# How can I use the mouse in VIM in FbTerm

Tags: vim, mouse

I have installed GPM and the mouse worked in VIM outside FbTerm. But when I open VIM in FbTerm in order to display Chinese characters, VIM works as if mouse is not enabled (without "set mouse=a"). In other words, there is a mouse cursor but the mouse cannot control the text cursor in VIM.

Comment: If you `:set mouse=a`, does it work or not?

Comment: @ryuichiro No. It does not work.

Comment: And was your Vim compiled with [`mouse_gpm`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/term.txt.html#gpm-mouse) feature enabled? You can check in `:version`.

Comment: @ryuichiro Yes. I have said that the mouse works in VIM outside FbTerm

Comment: I meant the instance you are running in FbTerm. It is better to check if it is not different from instances you are running outside of FbTerm (even though it is not probable). Last thought, have you compiled FbTerm with gpm support?

Comment: @ryuichiro I have checked that in FbTerm as well. mouse_gpm is also enabled in VIM in FbTerm.    I installed FbTerm by apt-get. I am not 100% sure the FbTerm is installed with gpm support but the mouse cursor works in FbTerm. I can move the mouse cursor, select some text and paste it in BASH in FbTerm.